# What is the most optimized way to include one set of DFP tags as a creative into another DFP account?

Tags: google-dfp

I have implemented dfp ad code across our site using what I'll call account A.

We have a contract with account B to serve ads with 100% fill on a couple of placements on our site.

Ad network B has provided us with a DFP account for the placements they are filling for us.  I can generate tags etc.

The way I have it set up now is that in Account A. I have created an order and line items for the units we want to fill with B's ads.  For the creative I am currently using the passback tags that I can generate in Account B and adding them to A as a third party creative.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
  googletag.pubads().definePassback('/XXXXX/XX/XX/XXX', [[1, 1], [320, 50], [728, 90], [160, 600], [300, 250]]).display();
</script>
```

Ads are being served, but the fill rate and # of impressions when serving B via A is down about 40% than when I put B's code directly into the page.  I suppose that could be a latency drop since I'm making an extra server trip, but that seems like an awfully large penalty.

What I'm wondering is whether this is the correct way to handle this.  I see the option for "DoubleClick Tag" creative in A, but I can't see how to generate or build that tag in B's interface.  Is there a standard format for "DoubleClick Tag" creatives that I would just build from what I know in B.

Of if there is a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that B isn't showing 100% fill on their end when running as a passback? This is an interesting setup, and I don't actually know if that's how it's supposed to display.

That said, I do know that when using passbacks, DFP is going to [double-count impressions](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1693146?hl=en). It'll show one impression for the initial request for Account A, and then again impression for the passback. That would halve your fill rate on Account A, even though you're still showing an ad on every page load. AFAIK, there's no way around this.

From Google's documentation:
[image: Double impression explanation from google]

Comment: B is showing 100% fill, but I think there may be requests that should be including ads from B, but aren't.  My question is mainly, What form of tag for account B should I be putting into the creative for that line item in Account A.  Seems like it shoudl be "DoubleClick Tag", but I don't know what that url for account B would look like.